# clearInterval not working on shuffle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

My clearInterval function is not working from a toggle button that I have created.

```
$('button.shuffle').click(function() {
  if(isShuffling) {
    clearInterval(discoLights);
    isShuffling = false;
    console.log('stop shuffling')
  } else {
    disco = setInterval(discoLights ,3000);
    isShuffling = true;
    console.log('start shuffling')
  }
});
```

I am aware that this kind of question has been asked numerous times. I did a lot of research on it within SO and I could not find solution to my problem.

Here is the JSFiddle of the code I have been working on: https://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/zLgsdno7/7/

I have tried reordering the code on several occasions, but nothing is working. I have used setInterval and clearInterval before on page load (not set with buttons) and I have not had an issue before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
clearInterval(disco);
```

instead of

```
clearInterval(discoLights);
```

As [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) takes the `id` which is returned by [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: OMG, I am going to facepalm myself! Such an obvious error. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in `clearInterval()`.

It should be `clearInterval(disco)` instead of

`clearInterval(dicoLights)`.

See [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Comment: Sorry dude, another dude beat you to the same answer, but upvote all the same.